# OpenCV: Converting from a Contour Tree to a Contour - cvContourFromContourTree()

Tags: opencv

I have a pointer to a CvContourTree and I wish to derive the associated contour from this.

I have tried to use the function that will do this -

cvContourFromContourTree(const CvContourTree* tree, CvMemStorage* storage, CvTermCriteria criteria )

but it is giving me an error:

'Unhandled exception at 0x1005567f in Matching_Hierarchial.exe: 0xC0000005: 
Access violation reading location 0x00000002.'

I have defined the CvTermCriteria as follows:

CvTermCriteria termcrit = cvTermCriteria(CV_TERMCRIT_ITER | CV_TERMCRIT_EPS ,5,1);

Can someone please provide some sample code of how to convert a contour to contour tree and then back to a contour again. I would be extremely grateful for help in this matter.
Thanks,

Conor

---

Thanks for your fast response. Please see the attched code segment. I have taken in an image from my project folder, converted it to binary. I have then found the contours. Using an arbitrary contour, I simplified its complexity via polygon approximation. I construct a contour tree from this contour (I am confident that this is working ok as I have tested this contour tree against a similar one using cvMatchContourTrees() and gotten favourable outcomes). However despite reading all I could find on the function and your post, I cannot convert from the contour tree back to the contour structure.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "cv.h"
#include "highgui.h"
#include "cxcore.h"
#include "cvaux.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#define CVX_RED CV_RGB(0xff,0x00,0x00)
#define CVX_BLUE CV_RGB(0x00,0x00,0xff)

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    // define input image
    IplImage *img1 = cvLoadImage("SHAPE1.jpg",0);

    // define and construct binary image of input image
    IplImage *imgEdge1 = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(img1),IPL_DEPTH_8U,1);
    cvThreshold(img1,imgEdge1,155,255,CV_THRESH_BINARY);

    // define and zero image to place polygon image
    IplImage *dst1 = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(img1),IPL_DEPTH_8U,1);
    cvZero(dst1);

    // display ip and thresholded image
    cvNamedWindow("img1",1);
    cvNamedWindow("thresh1",1);
    cvShowImage("img1",img1);
    cvShowImage("thresh1",imgEdge1);

    // find all the contours of the image
    CvSeq* contours1 = NULL;
    CvMemStorage* storage1 = cvCreateMemStorage();
    int numContour1 = cvFindContours(imgEdge1,storage1,&contours1,sizeof(CvContour),CV_RETR_TREE,CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
    cout<<"number of contours"<<numContour1<<endl;

    // extract a contour of interest
    CvSeq* poly_approx1 = contours1->v_next; // interested in vertical level becaue tree structure

    // CALCULATE PERIMETER
    double perimeter1 = cvArcLength((CvSeq*)poly_approx1,CV_WHOLE_SEQ,-1);

    // CREATE POLYGON APPROXIMATION - 
    // NB: CANNOT USE 'CV_CHAIN_CODE'ARGUEMENT IN THE cvFindContours() call 
    CvSeq* polySeq1 = cvApproxPoly((CvSeq*)poly_approx1,sizeof(CvContour),storage1,CV_POLY_APPROX_DP,perimeter1*0.02,0);

    // draw approximated polygon
    cvDrawContours(dst1,polySeq1,cvScalar(255),cvScalar(255),0,3,8);    // draw

    // display polygon
    cvNamedWindow("Poly Approx1",1);
    cvShowImage("Poly Approx1",dst1);

// NOW WE HAVE A POLYGON APPROXIMATED CONTOUR

    // CREATE A CONTOUR TREE
    CvMemStorage *treeStorage1 = cvCreateMemStorage(0);
    CvContourTree* tree1 = cvCreateContourTree((const CvSeq*)polySeq1,treeStorage1,0);

// TO RECONSTRUCT A CONTOUR FROM THE CONTOUR TREE
// CANNOT GET TO WORK YET...
    CvMemStorage *stor = cvCreateMemStorage(0);
    CvTermCriteria termcrit = cvTermCriteria(CV_TERMCRIT_ITER | CV_TERMCRIT_EPS ,5,1); // more later
    /* the next line will not compile */
    CvSeq *contour_recap = cvContourFromContourTree(tree1,treeStorage1,termcrit);


    cvWaitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks again for any help or advice that you might be able to give. I assure you it's greatly appreciated.

Conor

Answer (score 0):

Well, you are using the appropriate methods.

```
CvContourTree* cvCreateContourTree(
const CvSeq* contour,
CvMemStorage* storage,
double threshold);
```

This method will create the contour tree from a given sequence, which can then be used to compare two contours.
To convert a contour tree back to a sequence you will use the method you already posted, but remember to initialize the storage and create a TermCriteria(looks ok in your example):

```
storage = cvCreateMemStorage(0);
CvSeq* cvContourFromContourTree(
const CvContourTree* tree,
CvMemStorage* storage,
CvTermCriteria criteria);
```

So this steps should be ok for your conversion, and if there's nothing missing from your code than you should post more of it so we can find the mistake.